# how to render the view of component when calling the function from another component in angular4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-components

I have app.component like below

```
/*// 

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { DndComponent } from './dnd/dnd.component';

@Component({

  selector: 'app-root',

  template: ' (click)="sample()"',

  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

})

export class AppComponent {

constructor(public ob:DndComponent) {

}

sample(){

this.ob.changevar();
}

}


/*//
```

And,
I have another dnd component like

```
/*//

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({

  selector: 'dnd',

  template: '<div>{{name}}</div>',

  styleUrls: ['../app.component.css']

})

export class DndComponent {

name:string="saran"

constructor(){ 

}

changevar(){

this.name="kumar";
}

}

/*//
```

here, I am trying to change the name value with method calling from another component. The name value is updating but the view is not rendering.

is there any way to render the other component view dynamically with an on-click method from another component.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

When you want to call a function in one component on trigger of some event in another component, you can use event binding.  See my answer here [Call function from one component to another component Angularjs 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327708/call-function-from-one-component-to-another-component-angularjs-2/45328998#45328998).

This can be done only when one component is a part of another component. This is not valid for two independent components. If you are looking for this case, then please clarify in the description.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so clear about your question but based on this

> is there any way to render the other component view dynamically with
>   an on-click method from another component.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 
import { DndComponent } from './dnd/dnd.component';

@Component({

  selector: 'app-root',

  template: ' (click)="sample()"',

  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

})

export class AppComponent {

constructor(public ob:DndComponent, private router: Router) {

}

sample(){
this.router.navigate['/Dnd']
//this.ob.changevar();
}

}
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule, CanActivate} from '@angular/router';
import { PublicDealsComponent } from './public-deals.component';
import { DndComponent } from './dnd/dnd.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  // Add the redirect
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/appComponent',
    pathMatch: 'full',

  },
  {
    path: 'appComponent',
    component: AppComponent 
  },
  {
    path: 'Dnd',
    component: DndComponent ,

  },

];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);

export const routedComponents = [AppComponent , DndComponent ];
```

Comment: thanks k11k2 , this is view update with routing method but I want to update the variable value that is changed from another component in dnd component name=''saran" and the view is already loaded. in app component with a method calling i want change the name variable value from saran to kumar. This functionlity i want to do from another component.

Comment: @saran view is loading but name value is not changing?

Comment: the view is loading in the page load time. after that, I'm trying to change the name value from other component button click.         exactly the question is                Changing one component view content from another component button click . did u understand the question?

Comment: The value is changing but the view is not updating because i am doing click operation from different component

Comment: changed value is not updating on the current view ?

Comment: yes, from the same component with method calling both value and view are updating.but, from the different component with method calling value is updating but the view is not updating.

Comment: @saran firstly, can I know where your route navigation occurs ? , my guess is your routing to another view before method execution complete.

Comment: just think, I have 3 components.One is app-root and another one is ABC and third one is def. I am calling other two components in app-root with rout-outlet method . when page load the app-root and abc componets will load and web page will display. after that i am clikcing a button in app-root component view. it is calling a one of the method in the abc component. some content in the abc view i am trying to change. the problem is it is entering into the method in the abc componet and in the console i'm getting the updated data but in the view it is not updating

Comment: oh, why don't you use @Input() for sending values from parent to child component. Once try it. I have done this by using `@Input()` and `@Output()`

Comment: Yes, K11k2 I also tried with @Input() method. It is working for sending variable values. but I want to receive complete div code.and update in the another component

Comment: this would may help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274276/angular2-can-i-use-viewchild-and-input-at-the-same-time)